# Integrate Log Files in Gitlab CI / CD

Tags: logging, error-handling, gitlab

Is it possible that a gitlab pipeline shows log files (for example Tomcat Log) in the case of failure?

I could SSH to the server and tail it. But that requires that I have to setup every environment with appropriated public and private keys.

```
show log from test:
  stage: fail_handling
  when: on_failure
  script: ssh user@server tail /opt/logs/tomcat.log
```

Some Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats exactly the reason why there are artifacts: 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html

A common scenario would be that you provide the log files on failure and the built executable at success.